# Insert after each occurrence - Python

Tags: python, list, loops, insert

How to write a function that does the following -

After each occurrence of num1 in a list, insert num2

`def insert_after(lst, num1, num2):`

Answer (score 0):

In general, people on stack overflow would appreciate you to at least attempt a solution before asking for help. That being said, here is an O(1) solution that is the first to come to mind:

**PREVIOUS ANSWER WAS INCORRECT**

The best way to do this is as follow:
Iterating through the length of the list as I did before does not work, as the list is growing when you insert but you are iterating through a fixed number.

```
def insert_after(lst,num1,num2):
    output = []
    for num in lst:
        output.append(num)
        if num == num1:
            output.append(num2)
    return output
```

Comment: This does not work for consecutive numbers, like a list = [2, 2, 2] which, after running insert_after(list, 2, 100), gives [2, 100, 2, 100, 2] and not [2, 100, 2, 100, 2, 100].

Comment: Check my update, sorry about that

Comment: I think it has to do with consecutive integers not just the end of the list. For example, it does not work for this lst = [5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6]. Which gives [5, 1, 99, 2, 1, 99, 1, 6] and not [5, 1, 99, 2, 1, 99, 1, 99, 6].

Comment: Please a write a full code example. If you want the output `[5, 1, 99, 2, 1, 99, 1, 99, 6]` from `[5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6]`, then you must be running `func(lst,1,99)`. Testing that out with the code I added to my answer gives me the output as expected.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without creating a new list? A function that mutates the original list.

Comment: If you have an estimate of the what the final list length can you can iterate through that. You can also do a `while True:` loop, but this is a bad idea unless you have a solid way to get out of the loop. @Jako's solutions also make copies, but look cleaner, if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple fun ways using list comprehensions:

**Solution 1:**

```
lst = [1,5,4,3,5,5,7,8,9,6,5]

def insert_after_more_readable(lst,num1,num2):
    temp_lst = [[num] if num != num1 else [num, num2] for num in lst]
    final_lst = [elem for sublist in temp_lst for elem in sublist]
    return final_lst
print(lst, 5,8)
```

Explanation:

1. We create a list of lists called temp_lst. Every time we encounter num1, we insert a sublist [num1,num2], and otherwise we insert sublist [num].
2. We iterate over all the sublists, and take out all their elements and put them into the outer list.

**Solution 2:**

This is a less readable version, but the exact same thing using nested list comprehensions, all in one line.

```
lst = [1,5,4,3,5,5,7,8,9,6,5]
def insert_after(lst, num1, num2):
    return [elem for sublist in [[num] if num != num1 else [num,num2] 
for num in lst] for elem in sublist]
print(lst, 5,8)
```

In this version, the inner list that is formed is equivalent to temp_lst above.